# Add-in Error: Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in.

Tags: reactjs, office-js

I am using Create React App to build an add-in for Excel. The add-in works well in the Excel for macOS.

<kbd>[The Repo](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/office-addin-react)</kbd>

However, when I try to load it in Excel Online. After uploading the manifest file and opening the add-in, it shows

> Add-in Error: Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.

[image]

The console shows

> Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'ms-allow-popups' is an invalid sandbox flag.

I am already using HTTPS in development by `HTTPS=true npm start`.

What else may cause this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, how did you eventually fix this issue? -- I,m running into a similar issue and I cant guess what is going on here.

Comment: I have the same issue in Outlook plugin when I switched option displayInIframe from false into true , no react in my project

Comment: How were you able to see the console?  I'm not able to right click on the add-in taskpane in order to choose Inspect to see the console.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're hitting a timeout error. Make sure you're always handling [calling Office.initialize()](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment) before any other code.

For example, I would call `registerServiceWorker()` from within your init method. You have a lot of things going on in there and it is firing off at the same time as initialize at the moment.

```
Office.initialize = () => {

  registerServiceWorker();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

};
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I tried moving `registerServiceWorker() ` into `Office.initialize` before and behind `ReactDOM.render`, but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by your Office365 administrator changing their security settings to disallow all add-ins that have not been approved by your administrators.

If they **either** disable this restriction in the Office 365 admin system **or** add your add-in's manifest to the allowed list, after some propagation delay (minutes to days depending on the number of individuals in your Office365 tenant) you should find your add-in opens as normal.